# Getting 'No handlers could be found for logger "foursquare"' error using Flask on Heroku. Error doesn't occur when using localhost

Tags: python, heroku, flask, foursquare

I've got a website that uses the **Foursquare python API** and the **Flask framework**.

Everything has been working great, but when I pushed my code to my heroku server, I started getting this error: **FoursquareException: Error connecting with foursquare API**.

This is the code that is being run (the variables all point to the valid information):

```
fsq_client = Foursquare(client_id=fsq_client_id, client_secret=fsq_client_secret, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

@app.route('/fsq/explore')
def fsq_explore():
    lat = request.args.get('lat', '')
    lng = request.args.get('lng', '')
    params = {}
    params['ll'] = str(lat) + ',' + str(lng)
    data = fsq_client.venues.explore(params)
    return json.dumps(data)
```

I'm also seeing an error in my Heroku logs that says that **No handlers could be found for logger "foursquare"**.

I've never seen that error before.

I've tried running the code on my localhost, and everything is totally fine. I even input each line of code into python in terminal and it all returned correctly. It seems to be a problem specific to the Heroku server.

Is there anything that I should lookout for? Any setting I should play with or requirement I should make sure I have?

Comment: If it's working properly locally, but not on heroku, it's possible you're using some features that are not available in the Heroku environment. Try removing calls to the foursquare logger (which may not be available in Heroku). These calls may be triggering exceptions that interfere with your API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem on heroku. The error about the logger can be solved by putting this in your app.py (or wherever your Flask app is located):

```
import foursquare
import sys
import logging
loghandler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
foursquare.log.addHandler(loghandler)
foursquare.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

In Heroku everything that is writting through sys.stdout is saved in "heroku logs", so you will see the message that was written to the log there.

Then you can see what problem the foursquare library was raising, in my case it seems to be something with the SSL-certificates. I'm still working on that problem.